# git merge overwrites contents

Tags: git, git-merge

Here is my situation:

- I have two feature branches A & B.
- I want to combine these two branches.

I did the following:

- Create a new branch C branching off from A
- Checkout the new branch C
- run `git merge B` from command line

I expect both the branches combined. If there are conflicting changes to the same files the command should raise a merge conflict.

But in actual, there is a same file which has different contents in branches A and B but there was no merge conflict reported. Instead, the contents of the file from branch A are overwritten by the contents of the file from branch B.

I have no clue why there was not a merge conflict reported and am more worried why the contents of the file was overwritten.

Any hints or pointers would help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you link to the branches on GitHub?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant bits of `git log --graph --decorate --all`? Then we can see the relationship between the branches.

Comment: Is there anything odd in `git config -l`? And can you show us the *exact* sequence of commands you ran and the output of `git merge`?

Comment: maybe B was branched from A?

Comment: @JBallin do you mean provide links to the branches?

Comment: @blogs4t Did the merge mention a "fast-forward'?

Comment: @blogs4t Correct. You can also link to the repo and tell us the name of the branches and make sure they are pushed up.

Answer (score 1):

Let's lay out what happened.

> - I have two feature branches A & B.

This is usually something like this.

```
           4 - 5 [A]
          /
 1 - 2 - 3 - 6 [master]
              \
               7 - 8 [B]
```

A and B are branched off `master`. They diverge.

But you may have had this.

```
                 6 - 7 [B]
                /
           4 - 5 [A]
          /
 1 - 2 - 3 - 6 [master]
```

Here B is branched from A. B shares all of A's commits. Let's assume that.

> - Create a new branch C branching off from A

Creating a new branch in Git just makes a new label at the same commit as A.

```
                 6 - 7 [B]
                /
           4 - 5 [A][C]
          /
 1 - 2 - 3 - 6 [master]
```

> - Checkout the new branch C
> - run `git merge B` from command line

When this happens Git notices that C is an ancestor of B. So it does a "fast-forward" meaning it doesn't bother with a merge, it just advances C to where B is.

```
                 6 - 7 [B][C]
                /
           4 - 5 [A]
          /
 1 - 2 - 3 - 6 [master]
```

If A and B changed the same files it would appear that B overwrote the changes in A.

`git log` and Github unfortunately flatten out your Git history giving you a false impression that it's linear. You can see the true structure of your repository with `git log --graph --decorate --all` and check if it matches the scenario here.

Comment: in my case, I could see both branches A and B are branched off from master (may not be at the same time though). If so, should i create my branch C off from master - then merge A into C and  - then merge B into C? in order to have no missing commits from both A and B?