# How can Git override changes from past commits if I don't see any conflict when pulling/pushing?

Tags: git

After pulling my colleague's last few commits before pushing mine, my own changes were correctly merged however my colleagues' changes were overridden by my commits.

Why is this happening?

Note that I use standard Git CLI, he uses PHPstorm GUI. When this issue occurs, it is always his changes that get discarded, never mine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55149911/git-merge-overwrites-contents

Comment: But we're working on the same branch always

Comment: Forget about the branch names for a while. The names are meant to let you ignore the fact that what Git actually uses are commit hash IDs. Concentrate on the actual *hash IDs*, and look into what happens with each *commit* when you use `git push` or `git fetch` or `git merge`.

Comment: Did either of you force push?

Comment: None of us force pushed

Comment: It must have to do with the way you and he "merge the changes in". Can you investigate on how exactly he's proceeding in PHPStorm, and also post your pull command? It'll help to sort it out.

Comment: Does this happen only when you work on similar lines in the same file? When you look at the file history, do you see his changes?

Comment: The issue is it happens with files that I didn't even touch. I've been moving away from Git CLI in favor of Github Desktop for a week now and the problem hasn't occurred yet. If it continues over the next few weeks I'll have to conclude that Git CLI merging process is problematical (but not the one of GH Desktop)